# How can I implement a box shadow element in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Please see the box attached. I want to implement that box in swift. How can I do it?

Here's the CSS:

```
background: #FFFFFF;
border: 1px solid #DAD9D9;
box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
border-radius: 30px 30px 0px 0px;
```

Here's what I tried:

```
 self.answerView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor(red: 0.00, green: 0.00, blue: 0.00, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
 self.answerView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.25
 self.answerView.layer.cornerRadius = 30
 self.answerView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 2, height: 2);
 self.answerView.layer.shadowRadius = 0
```

[image]

Comment: Please show what your current result is in Swift.

Comment: When you say "I want to implement that box," do you mean the box containing the label, textfield, and button or do you just mean the textfield?

Comment: By 'box' do you mean a shadow, a border, and rounded corners on the top two corners of a view?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
self.answerView.borderStyle = .none
self.answerView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
self.answerView.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemGray3.cgColor
self.answerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemBackground
    
self.answerView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.systemGray3.cgColor
self.answerView.layer.shadowOpacity = 1
self.answerView.layer.shadowRadius = 0
self.answerView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 2.5);
self.answerView.layer.shadowRadius = 0
    
self.answerView.borderColor = UIColor.systemGray3
self.answerView.borderWidth = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to round the top corners, you should set the appropriate values to CALayer.maskedCorners.